# Combobox resets SelectedIndex to zero on dropdown change

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox which is bound to a datasource. and the datasource is updated on keypress event so that combobox.Items.count is variable and sometimes becomes zero.
every time the combobox is droppeddown or closed, combobox.selectedindex is reset to zero, and if items count is also zero this causes an ArgumentOutOfRange exception.
How can i prevent selectedindex change on combobox dropdown or close dropdown?

this is part of code that is placed in the keypress event handler:

```
DataRow[] rows = AllProfilesTable2.Select(string.Format("FullName LIKE '%{0}%'", strFindStr));
DataTable filteredTable = AllProfilesTable2.Clone();
foreach (DataRow r in rows)
  filteredTable.ImportRow(r);

cb.DataSource = null;
cb.DataSource = filteredTable.DefaultView;
cb.DisplayMember = "FullName";
cb.ValueMember = "ID";
if (cb.Items.Count > 0) {
  cb.DroppedDown = true;
  cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
  cb.Text = strFindStr;
  cb.SelectionStart = strFindStr.Length;
}
else {
  cb.DroppedDown = true;
  cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
  cb.Text = strFindStr;
  cb.SelectionStart = strFindStr.Length;
}
```

Comment: please show a little bit of code-efforts. we like to see code!

Comment: @Coffee i have added some code.

Comment: If you are getting an exception in the SelectedIndexChanged event, you should probably show us that code.  Otherwise, you could just remove the handler at the beginning of this code and add it back in at the end of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if your binding source is valid before binding to it. The `ComboBox` has a `DropDownClosed` event which occurs when the menu is closed. You can manipulate it from here.
I assume the reset issue just occurs when the menu is closed without any item selected.

MSDN says:

> To deselect the currently selected item, set the SelectedIndex to -1. You cannot set the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox item to -1 if the item is a data-bound item.

Source: [MSDN - ComboBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)